# tkinter.Toplevel size automatically fit its widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made my custom infobox class, `InfoBox`, that I am using in my application. The `tk.messagebox.showinfo` did not suit my needs to the poor shape. But `InfoBox` does not adjust its size to fit the widgets I place inside. How can I make it as small as possible without cutting the widgets?

The class receives a string, `msg`, and a PhotoImage object, `image`, which are placed in the InfoBox. I added a screenshot of one such InfoBox.

```
class InfoBox(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, msg, image):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.msg = msg
        self.image = image

        self.title = "Gassy"
        self.font = font.Font(family="Optima", size=20)

        frame_left = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_right = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        tk.Label(frame_left, image=self.image).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N)

        textbox = tk.Text(frame_right, font=self.font)
        textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        textbox.insert(tk.END, self.msg)
        textbox.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        tk.Button(frame_left, text="Den er grei!", font=self.font, command=self.destroy).grid(row=1, column=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having some trouble replicating your problem. When I run your code (after adding the necessary imports and instantiations of classes etc), the resulting window is exactly large enough to contain all of its widgets. Can you provide a [mcve], complete with import statements and InfoBox/mainloop calls?

Answer (score 2):

As @kevin mentioned, it works as intended, the `textwidget` is mostly empty and occupies a large blank area, this is what makes you think that the geometry manager is not shrinking the window to the widgets.

this:

(I removed the images and fonts that were not provided, and unnecessary)

```
import tkinter as tk

class InfoBox(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, msg):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.msg = msg

        self.title = "Gassy"

        frame_left = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_right = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

#         textbox = tk.Text(frame_right) 
#         textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
#         textbox.insert(tk.END, self.msg)
#         textbox.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        tk.Button(frame_left, text="Den er grei!", command=self.destroy).grid(row=1, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()
info = InfoBox(root, '123 ' * 1000)
root.mainloop()
```

produces that:

[image]

whereas that:

```
import tkinter as tk

class InfoBox(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, msg):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.msg = msg

        self.title = "Gassy"

        frame_left = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_right = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        textbox = tk.Text(frame_right) 
        textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        textbox.insert(tk.END, self.msg)
        textbox.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        tk.Button(frame_left, text="Den er grei!", command=self.destroy).grid(row=1, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()
info = InfoBox(root, '123 ' * 1000)
root.mainloop()
```

produces this:

[image]

Clearly, the `Toplevel` subclass adjusts its size to the widgets it contains

The test widget is displayed at a certain size, regardless of its content. The `Toplevel` resizes around the widgets, NOT around whatever is inserted in the text widget; like with a text processor rudimentary window, the text processor does not shrink or expand as text is typed or edited. The same applies here.
The keyword args `width` and `height` allow to configure the size (as a number of characters, or lines) of a text widget

Comment: Interesting. The `msg` I insert is a triple-quoted string. Perhaps that affects the size of the textbox?

Comment: maybe - although an empty text field also produces a popup with a large area occupied by that widget.

Comment: If I use your code, but reduce the number of `123 `s to insert to 10, then it does not resize properly. Inserting 1000 `123 `s fills the lines of the textbox, and therefore appears to have been properly resized?

Comment: You are welcome... The test widget is displayed at a certain size, regardless of its content. The `Toplevel` resizes around the widgets, NOT around whatever you insert in the text widget - think of it as a text processor rudimentary window: your text processor does not shrink or expand as you type or edit, does it? The same applies here.

Comment: The keyword args `width` and `height` allow you to configure the size (as a number of characters, or lines) of a text widget.